# Managing multiple tenant database connections using Simple Injector

Tags: database-connection, simple-injector, multi-tenant

Have a SharePoint "remote web" application that will be managing data for multiple tenant databases (and thus, ultimately, multiple tenant database connections). In essence, each operation will deal with 2 databases.

The first is our tenancy database, where we store information that is specific for each tenant. This can be the SharePoint OAuth Client ID and secret, as well as information about how to connect to the tenant's specific database, which is the second database. This means that connecting to the first database will be required before we can connect to the second database.

I believe I know how to do this using Simple Injector for HTTP requests. I could register the first connection type (whether that be an IDbConnection wrapper using ADO.NET or a TenancyDbContext from entity framework) with per web request lifetime.

I could then register an abstract factory to resolve the connections to the tenant-specific databases. This factory would depend on the first database type, as well as the Simple Injector Container. Queries & commands that need to access the tenant database will depend on this abstract factory and use it to obtain the connection to the tenant database by passing an argument to a factory method.

My question mainly has to do with how to handle this in the context of an operation that may or may not have a non-null `HttpContext.Current`. When a SharePoint app is installed, we are sometimes running a WCF `.svc` service to perform certain operations. When SharePoint invokes this, sometimes `HttpContext` is null. I need a solution that will work in both cases, for both database connections, and that will make sure the connections are disposed when they are no longer needed.

I have some older example code that uses the LifetimeScope, but I see now that there is an Execution Context Scoping package available for Simple Injector on nuget. I am wondering if I should use that to create hybrid scoping for these 2 database connections (with / without HTTP context), and if so, how is it different from lifetime scoping using `Container.GetCurrentLifetimeScope` and `Container.BeginLifetmeScope`?

**Update**

I read up on the execution scope lifestyle, and ended up with the following 3-way hybrid:

```
var hybridDataAccessLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid( // create a hybrid lifestyle
    lifestyleSelector: () => HttpContext.Current != null, // when the object is needed by a web request
    trueLifestyle: new WebRequestLifestyle(), // create one instance for all code invoked by the web request
    falseLifestyle: Lifestyle.CreateHybrid( // otherwise, create another hybrid lifestyle
        lifestyleSelector: () => OperationContext.Current != null,  // when the object is needed by a WCF op,
        trueLifestyle: new WcfOperationLifestyle(), // create one instance for all code invoked by the op
        falseLifestyle: new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle()) // in all other cases, create per execution scope
);
```

However my question really has to do with how to create a dependency which will get its connection string sometime after the root is already composed. Here is some pseudo code I came up with that implements an idea I have for how to implement this:

```
public class DatabaseConnectionContainerImpl : IDatabaseConnectionContainer, IDisposable
{
    private readonly AllTenantsDbContext _allTenantsDbContext;
    private TenantSpecificDbContext _tenantSpecificDbContext;
    private Uri _tenantUri = null;

    public DatabaseConnectionContainerImpl(AllTenantsDbContext allTenantsDbContext)
    {
        _allTenantsDbContext = allTenantsDbContext;
    }

    public TenantSpecificDbContext GetInstance(Uri tenantUri)
    {
        if (tenantUri == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(“tenantUri”);
        if (_tenantUri != null && _tenantUri.Authority != tenantUri.Authority)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "You can only connect to one tenant database within this scope.");

        if (_tenantSpecificDbContext == null) {
            var tenancy = allTenantsDbContext.Set<Tenancy>()
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Authority == tenantUri.Authority);
            if (tenancy == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                    "Tenant with URI Authority {0} does not exist.", tenantUri.Authority));

            _tenantSpecificDbContext = new TenantSpecificDbContext(tenancy.ConnectionString);
           _tenantUri = tenantUri;
        }
        return _tenantSpecificDbContext
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        if (_tenantSpecificDbContext != null) _tenantSpecificDbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The bottom line is that there is a runtime `Uri` variable that will be used to determine what the connection string will be to the `TenantSpecificDbContext` instance. This Uri variable is passed into all WCF operations and HTTP web requests. Since this variable is not known until runtime after the root is composed, I don't think there is any way to inject it into the constructor.

Any better ideas than the one above, or will the one above be problematic?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to run operations in two different contexts (one with the availability of the web request, and when without) within the same AppDomain, you need to use an [hybrid lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#hybrid). Hybrid lifestyles switch automatically from one lifestyle to the other. The example given in the Simple Injector documentation is the following:

```
ScopedLifestyle scopedLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    lifestyleSelector: () => container.GetCurrentLifetimeScope() != null,
    trueLifestyle: new LifetimeScopeLifestyle(),
    falseLifestyle: new WebRequestLifestyle());

// The created lifestyle can be reused for many registrations.
container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>(hybridLifestyle);
container.Register<ICustomerRepository, SqlCustomerRepository>(hybridLifestyle);
```

Using this custom hybrid lifestyle, instances are stored for the duration of an active lifetime scope, but we fall back to caching instances per web request, in case there is no active lifetime scope. In case there is both no active lifetime scope and no web request, [an exception will be thrown](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#dont-allow-resolving-outside-an-active-scope).

With Simple Injector, a scope for a web request will implicitly be created for you under the covers. For the lifetime scope however this is not possible. This means that you have to begin such scope yourself explicitly (as shown [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perlifetimescope)). This will [be trivial for you](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#decorators-with-func-t-decoratee-factories) since you use command handlers.

Now your question is about the difference between the [lifetime scope](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perlifetimescope) and [execution context scope](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perexecutioncontextscope). The difference between the two is that a lifetime scope is thread-specific. It can't flow over asychronous operations that might jump from thread to thread. It uses a [ThreadLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under the covers.

The execution scope however can be used in case you use async/wait and return `Task<T>` from you methods. In this case the scope can be disposed on a different thread, since it stores all cached instances in the [CallContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

In most cases you will be able to use the execution scope in places where you would use lifetime scope, but certainly not the other way around. But if your code doesn't flow asynchronously, lifetime scope gives better performance (although probably not really a significant performance difference from execution scope).

Comment: Thanks Steven. I was already using a hybrid scope because I need the same composition root to work for both WCF and regular HTTP. I have updated my question to make it more clear what I am after.